# Cannot see Display Suite menu under Administration

Tags: 7, routes, caching, display-suite

I am following this [training](http://tutr.tv/t5820). I have downloaded the module and have also enabled it. The video mentions a new 'Display Menu' under 'Administration'. I can't see it, though I am logged in as an administrator.

What am I doing wrong? (I am still new to Drupal)

**UPDATE**

I just tried to install the Module on a fresh install, and I don't get an issue there. Looks like my current system is corrupted. Is there any tool to 'correct' it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing your drupal cache, or alternatively try visiting the URL directly under `admin/structure/ds`

Comment: I cleared the cache, but it did not solve the issue. I tried via the URL, but it displays the same page as admin/structure. I double-checked, the module is enabled.

Comment: Ok, I just tried to clear the cache a third time and it worked... Really have no idea what happened here. Thanks !!